# How does SequenceEqual work in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming

I have a hard time to figure out how the SequenceEqual works in Reactive Extensions version 2.2.5

Below is the code

```
var subject1 = new Subject<int>();
            var subject2 = new Subject<int>();

            IObservable<bool> sequenceEqual = subject1.SequenceEqual(subject2);

            subject1.OnNext(5);
            subject1.OnNext(3);

            subject2.OnNext(1);
            subject2.OnNext(4);

            //This will be notified if the two sequences completed
            sequenceEqual.Subscribe(b => Console.WriteLine("Two sequences are equal ? {0}", b));

            subject1.OnCompleted();
            subject2.OnCompleted();
```

I expected that the output would be **"Two sequences are equal? False"**, but the result was **True** even they contained different elements.

[image: Sequence Equal]

I'm just wondering why the result was like that? What does the SequenceEqual actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SequenceEquals it will monitor from the point you Subscribe. So Subscribe before the OnNext calls and you'll get false in your subscription code or use ReplaySubjects.

Comment: The behavior is a little bit weird because I expected that it monitored at the point of my declaration, not at the point that I subscribed to notifications.

Comment: Yes totally agree. It feels more like the SequenceEquals should return a connectable observable as the subject seems to become 'hot' from the equality perspective.